# Many to Many in MongoDB - How do I refer to the subdorument of another document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to find a way of representing relationship between users through nicknames.

Each user has one or more nicknames, and zero or more contacts. For example, there is

User A with nicknames: Banana and Kiwi

And User B with nicknames: Apple, Pear, Cherry.

A has a contact: 
    {
        underNickname: Banana,
        toNickname: Apple
    }

B has a contact:
    {
        underNickname: Apple,
        toNickname: Banana
    }

I have a User schema which among other fields conatins a sub-collection of Contact:

```
const Contact = {
  underNickname: String,
  nickname: String
}

const UserSchema = new Schema()

UserSchema.add({
    nicknames: [Nickname],
    contacts: [Contact],
})
```

So the question is, how do I define this relationship in the user schema, so that its contacts refer to nicknames of itself (underNickname) and other users (toNickname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I found so far is to use the populate method: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html